# Can I use forward numerical referencing in Detailed Description?

Tags: provisional-application

I am drafting a Provisional Application. I have two drawings.

Figure 1 : (1.01,1.03)

Figure 8 : (8.01,8.03) as part numbers.

In the detailed description of Fig 1, can I take the reference of 8.01? I read several patents, so far I see, in the detailed description of Fig 8, they may refer to Figure 1 parts, but now reverse. I know that as per guidelines one has to use the same number for a part across the literature. Please share your thoughts.

Alternatively, I can take a separate paragraph for if I want to explain Figure 1 and Figure 8 collectively.

Could you please share suggestions.

Comment: Are there any parts that show up in both figures?

Comment: Yes. In the above example, I can include Part number 1.05 which can also appear in Figure 1 and Figure 8 as well. In other words, part 1.05 may present in multiple figures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can describe it in whatever way you want. You can start with numeral 17000 in fig. 17, afterwards describe numeral 42 in fig. 3 and it really doesn't matter. Just make sure it's understandable for the examiner.